# constness cast undefined behaviour

Tags: c, gcc

Could the return cast (==>) give place to an undefined behavior? the idea of the code is very simple, iterate through an intrusive list (plist) and return the element if found. Since the code only iterates it doesn't change the list so I want to pass it as a const pointer.

```
static my_custom_type_t* get_object_by_id(const my_custom_type_t* plist, const char *my_id)
{
   const my_custom_type_t* obj = NULL;

  for (obj = plist; obj && strncmp(obj->id, my_id, MAX_SIZE); obj = obj->next)
  {
     ; //empty body
  }

   ==> return ((my_custom_type_t*) obj);
}
```

When the function is used to get an object and use it as const:

```
const my_custom_type_t* obj = get_object_by_id(intrusive_list, some_id);
```

When the function is used to get an object and use it as non-const object:

```
my_custom_type_t* obj = get_object_by_id(intrusive_list, some_id);
```

Comment: Think over what "const-correctness" means. Of course your code breaks it! And never use a cast if you are not completely aware of all implications.

Comment: In this case constness is the list structure, since the function is not modifying the list so it's not broken, isn't? I mean somebody outside this method could later use the pointer to modify the intrusive list, but the function get_object_by_id is not modifying the "prev/next" pointers.

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply return a `const` pointer as well?

Comment: I would not have written that comment if it was not broken. Each time you assign a `const` `whatever` to a non-`const` `whatever` you break it. `const` is a guarantee **you** give to the compiler, not the other way 'round.

Comment: The get_object_by_id is being passed to other functions, some times as const pointer and others not. So when I need a const object I use:  const my_custom_type_object* and when I only need a modifiable object I use a simple my_custom_type_object*

Comment: This is a problem that occurs with some standard C library functions — `strchr()` for example: `char *
     strchr(const char *s, int c);` returns a non-constant pointer to part of the constant string argument.  C++ doesn't like this; it has overloaded functions to deal with the problem, one for constant inputs returning a constant pointer, and one for non-constant inputs returning a non-constant pointer.

Comment: So your other code is wrong, too.

Comment: ^ What Olaf said. The correct solution is to fix your code, not (possibly) break your data.

Comment: I don't get your point. I said depending on the place I use a const or not depending on what I'm trying to do with the object. As Jonathan Leffler says this in C++ could be resolved by overloading ... In C I have to create two different functions !! I would like to avoid this ..

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: This is not an error in the function declaration, but allows to pass `const` and non-const qualified pointers. (but yes, it does break type-safety). Nevertheless you can assign the result of `strchr` to a `const char *`.

Comment: @redobot: In case you address me (hard to say without proper addressing): The point is you should reconsider your interface. At that level most code breaking const-correctness is because of bad inderface design. Depending on the project, interface design is more than 50% of programming job.

Comment: In this case the cast to non-const is justified, assuming the object weren't defined with const. The code uses a pointer to const to search for an object, which is good to prevent unintentional modification, and when the object is found, a non-const pointer to the object is returned.

Comment: @Olaf yes, thanks for your comments. In this case I'm trying to avoid creating two functions: get_const_object_by_id and get_object_by_id.

Comment: So, like the implementers of `strchr()` in C, you have to cast the return value to non-const.  The user of the function needs to know that if by some mischance the list item that's found is truly `const` (improbable, but not necessarily impossible) and they subsequently try modifying the item via the non-const pointer, then all hell breaks loose.  This is usually an acceptable risk — witness `strchr()`.  You might (or might not) want to consider the merits of `#define CONST_CAST(type, value) ((type)(value))` (which can be given a C++ implementation `const_cast<type>(value)`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Ehm, you don't have to cast `strchr` to non-`const`.

Comment: @Olaf: Inside the implementation of `strchr()`, you have to coerce the constant pointer you're passed into a non-constant pointer that you return, possibly after changing its value (so it points to the character sought).  From the outside, there's no major problem; it's on the inside that the cast is necessary — implicitly, perhaps, if you decide to just do `return const_pointer;` (but that's sloppy coding; the compiler does coerce the returned pointer so it is non-constant).  The same for this implementation.  For the user, it is basically a non-issue.  It is an issue for the implementer.

Comment: @Olaf: and yes, it is mostly a book-keeping issue.  On most machines, there isn't a bit that says "this is a pointer to constant data".  Mind you, I would not be surprised to find that there were some mainframe architectures that did so tag pointers.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your responses. In my case the user is responsible for choosing what pointer to use (const or not) depending on the context.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I prefer to leave this decision to the user. After all, he should know if the pointer passed is `const` or not. For the standard library, legacies from pre-`const` times forbid this. I'm afraid we will not see those legacies being removed from the standard. For user-libraries/modules, one should use a more modern approach and leave breaking const-correctness to where it is known to be safe.

Comment: @Olaf: I think we're verging on the "if you want C++, you know where to find it" discussion.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I don't think so. As I wrote: I'd make the function return a `const` pointer, being const-correct. The caller shall then cast the result if necessary, because it does know what he passed as argument. But an optimal solution would have to consider the whole context including the type declarations not shown in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C specifies conversions from pointers to qualified-pointers, but not the other way around, C11 6.3.2.3/2:

> For any qualifier q, a pointer to a non-q-qualified type may be
>   converted to a pointer to the q-qualified version of the type; the
>   values stored in the original and converted pointers shall compare
>   equal.

However, C allows the following, C11 6.3.2.3/7:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly
>   aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.
>   Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal
>   to the original pointer.

In plain English, *any* pointer type may be converted to *any other* pointer type and back. If there are no alignment issues with the pointer itself, such code is fine unless the pointer is converted to a non-compatible type and then de-referenced. A qualified-pointer-to-type is always a compatible type of pointer-to-type.

(Note that this refers to pointers to object type - function pointers is a special case.)

So whether this is UB or not really depends on where that pointer originally pointed. You invoke UB in the following case, C11 6.7.3/6:

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a
>   const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified
>   type, the behavior is undefined.

If the pointer originally pointed at a read-only location, you would invoke undefined behavior. But if it pointed at a non-const, allocated variable, it would be fine. For example, this code is fine and does not invoke undefined behavior:

```
type t;
type* p = (type*)(const type*)&t1;
```

Otherwise, as someone pointed out in comments, several of the C standard library functions would be fundamentally broken, for example `strstr`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. In this case the intrusive list is composed by objects allocated by the user in the heap (dynamic allocation by malloc). So I think the code should be correct taking into account your explanation.

Comment: @redobot For that case, C has rules about "effective type", which states what type the allocated chunk of memory will get treated as. In order to tell if the code is safe or not, we'd have to see the caller code.

Comment: I can't post the caller code because it's quit large. But basically there places where you get the object from the list and treat it as modifiable   and others where the object is treated as const because we don't want the called function to modify its internals.

Answer (score 0):

> Could the return cast (==>) give place to an undefined behavior?

No. casting a `(my_custom_type_t*)` to `(const my_custom_type_t*)` does not cause UB.

Neither does either of the below cause UB

```
const my_custom_type_t* plist1;
const my_custom_type_t* obj1 = get_object_by_id(plist1, "x");
printf("%d\n", obj1->some_field);

my_custom_type_t* plist2;
my_custom_type_t* obj2 = get_object_by_id(plist2, "x");
obj2->some_field = 2;
```

Yet the following *does* invoke UB ...

```
const my_custom_type_t* plist3;
my_custom_type_t* obj3 = get_object_by_id(plist3, "x");

// UB
obj3->some_field = 3;
```

To avoid this potential, write 2 functions, one being a wrapper of the other.

```
static const my_custom_type_t* get_object_by_id_const(
    const my_custom_type_t* plist, const char *my_id) {
  // as above in OP's post
  return obj;
}

static my_custom_type_t* get_object_by_id_noconst(
    my_custom_type_t* plist, const char *my_id) {
  const my_custom_type_t* obj = get_object_by_id_const(plist, my_id);
  return (my_custom_type_t*) obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case the const in the in the reverse order:  (const my_custom_type_t*) to (my_custom_type_t*) which could be problematic as explained by Lundin's answer. If you read the comments I didn't want to have two functions for const and no-cont.

Comment: @redobot Best to edit critical requirements to the post rather than only in the comments.  Well after writing a chuck of this answer I did see "I'm trying to avoid creating two functions:" which subtly differs from your latest comment "I didn't want".  [You can't always get what you want,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BykilS816E) but this answer may be what code needs.

Comment: @redobot Look into `_Generic` for a common interface solution.

Comment: your are right, I'm sorry. I forgot to update the question with this important detail. Thanks for your answer anyway.